# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: c. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Tags: c#-4.0

I know the question is asked before but i tried all the options and could not get ride of it . my code is something like this

```
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string url = "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/StockData";
            string EncryptedJson = client.DownloadString(url);
            var dataresponse = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(EncryptedJson);
```

and at deserialzeObject it is throwing the exception

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: c. Path '', line
>   0, position 0.

while the client.DownloadString(url) is giving data in the following format

> callback([{"Date":"/Date(1196467200000)/","Close":40.635,"Volume":1650185491,"Open":40.640,"High":40.680,"Low":39.090}])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not JSON, it's JSONP.

Remove the `callback(` at the start and the `)` at the end to make it JSON:

```
EncryptedJson = EncryptedJson.Substring(9, EncryptedJson.Length - 10);
```

Comment: @ImranNaqvi: The `Substring` in the answer removes both the `callback(` at the beginning and the `)` at the end. Notice that it skips 9 characters from the start, and 10 is subtracted from the length, so it removes one character from the end also.